# Regex to match TestMethods

Tags: c#, regex, unit-testing

For our application we have about 4000 Unit-tests which will be automatically executed if we check-in your code to the tfs.

We've changed a lot at our Build-Definition so now it is required that all unit-tests must have the attribute `[TestCategory(TestCategories.GatedCheckin)]` to be executed within the gated-checkin.

Unfortunately only 700 Unittest of the 4000 already have this attribute. Now I have to add the attribute to the remaining unit-tests.

Therefor I've written a small VisualStudio-Extension where I can open source file and search for the following regular expression:

```
^([\t]|[ ])*\[TestMethod\]([\t]|[ ]|[\w\/äÄüÜöÖß])*([\r\n]+)([\t]|[ ])*public
```

This regular expression just works fine for unit-tests like:

```
[TestMethod]
public void PathIsValidTest1()
{...}
```

or

```
[TestMethod] // another test
public void Calculator_Add_3_And_3_Equals_6_Test()
{...}
```

But for unittest which also contains another attribute like:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
public void ThrowOnInputTooLongTest2()
{...}
```

the regular expression doesn't work.

How can I modify the regular expression, so it matches all Unittests with the `[TestMethod]` attribute and not the `[TestCategory(TestCategories.GatedCheckin)]`

I thougt about a negative lookahead with `?!` but I didn't get it to work.

Any ideas?

---

I've modified the solution provided by Addison so it looks like:

```
^[\t ]*\[TestMethod\][ \t\w\/äÄüÜöÖß]*(\n([ \t]*)\[(?!TestCategory\(TestCategories\.GatedCheckin\)).+\][ \t\w\/äÄüÜöÖß]*)?\s+public
```

If I use this in regex101 it just works fine as you can see [here](https://regex101.com/r/EJx7xe/3)

But if I use this regex in c# with:

```
string content = File.ReadAllText(file);    
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);
int matchCount = regex.Matches(content).Count;
```

I only get 2 matches.

Comment: Can you provide any guarantee (or assumption) about the order of the attributes for the unit tests? i.e: will the `[TestMethod]` attribute always/usually be first?

Comment: `[TestMethod]` is always the first attribute

Comment: Perfect! Then my solution should work. Please give it a go, and provide any examples if it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question!

I managed to do it with this:

```
^[\t ]*\[TestMethod\][ \t\w\/äÄüÜöÖß]*(\n\[(?!TestCategory\(TestCategories\.GatedCheckin\)).+\][ \t\w\/äÄüÜöÖß]*)*\s+public
```

I added in another catching field (and simplified the rest of the regex) so that it now checks for any number of other `[]` AFTER the first `[TestMethod]`, and will accept them if and only if none of them are `[TestCategory(TestCategories.GatedCheckin)]`.

[Test it online](https://regex101.com/r/EJx7xe/2)

Here is some C# code to do it:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Programming {
    class Program {
        static void Main() {
            string content = "namespace MyNameSpace1\n{\n    [TestClass]\n    public class GetMapPathActionTests\n    {\n        [TestMethod] // 1\n        public void GetMapPath_with_All_Attibutes()\n        {\n            ...\n        }\n        [TestMethod] // 2\n        [ExpectedException(typeof(DBInstallInfoConverterCrossCheckerRequiredChildNotFoundException))]\n        public void GetMapPath_with_Empty_Input()\n        {\n           \n        }\n        [TestMethod] // 3\n        [ExpectedException(typeof(DBInstallInfoConverterCrossCheckerRequiredChildNotFoundException))]\n        public void GetMapPath_with_Empty_Output()\n        {\n            \n        }\n        [TestMethod] // 4\n        public void GetMapPath_with_Empty()\n        {\n            \n        }\n        [TestMethod] // 5\n        [ExpectedException(typeof(DBInstallInfoConverterCrossCheckerRequiredChildNotFoundException))]\n        public void GetMapPath_with_All_Attibutes_Empty()\n        {\n            \n        }\n    }\n}\n";
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[\t ]*\[TestMethod\][ \t\w\/äÄüÜöÖß]*(\s+\[(?!TestCategory\(TestCategories\.GatedCheckin\)).+\][ \t\w\/äÄüÜöÖß]*)?\s+public", RegexOptions.Multiline);
            MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(content);

            foreach (Match match in matches) {
                foreach (Capture capture in match.Captures) {
                    Console.WriteLine(capture.Value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've modified your solution a bit so it also matches if there are \t or ' ' before the next attribute. Now it looks like: `^[\t ]*\[TestMethod\][ \t\w\/äÄüÜöÖß]*(\n([ \t]*)\[(?!TestCategory\(TestCategories\.GatedCheckin\)).+\][ \t\w\/äÄüÜöÖß]*)?\s+public`   In the regex101 it just works fine. If I use it within my c#-code I don't get all hits

Comment: Also, what IDE are you using @Tomtom

Comment: VisualStudio2017

Comment: Which hits are you missing? Please give an example if your original question

Comment: And please make sure you aren't using the wrong regex. Use this: `^[\t ]*\[TestMethod\][ \t\w\/äÄüÜöÖß]*(\n([ \t]*)\[(?!TestCategory\(TestCategories\.GatedCheckin\)).+\][ \t\w\/äÄüÜöÖß]*)*\s+public`

Comment: In the link which I added to the question I only get the TestMethod //1 and // 4

Comment: I am unable to duplicate this issue, when using Visual Studio Code, and C#. You must have a problem with your configuration, or potentially you have a mix of windows and unix newlines `\r\n` and `\n`.

Comment: If I change the \n to \r\n in the regex it works. Thank you!